# ¿Cómo tomar una variable con AJAX, JavaScript o JQuery al momento de que es cambiada?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, php7

Compañeros, necesito ayuda.

Estoy intentando hacer que una variable JavaScript se modifique al tiempo que una variable PHP lo hace.

Es decir, el .php recibe una variable por el método POST; el JavaScript de ese .php tiene que recibir y definir la variable php como una variable JavaScript. Si la variable recibida por el método POST se modifica, la variable JavaScript también.

He intentado crear una función change, pero no me funciona:

```js
/*function enviar_categoria() {
         var buscarc=$("#buscarc").text();
         alert(buscarc);
        }
        $(document).on("change", "form" function(){
         var buscarc=$("#buscarc").text();
         alert(buscarc);
        })
        $("#buscarc").change(function(){
         var buscarc=$("#buscarc").text();
         alert(buscarc);
        })*/
        $(document).on("change", "#buscarc" function(){
         var buscarc=$("#buscarc").text();
         alert(buscarc);
          })
```

```html
<font id='buscarc' onchange='enviar_categoria();' contenteditable>Aceites</font>
```

Como pueden ver, he intentado 4 opciones, pero no funcionaron. Uso el alert para saber que el código funciona. Por favor, si alguien tiene una mejor idea, o me corrige, sería muy agradecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función ajax de Jquery es la siguiente: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, no la estás usando en tu código. Si lo que buscas es inyectar una variable PHP en el código Javascript. Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
<script>
var variable = '<?=$_POST['variable']?>';
</script>
```

Por otro lado, si lo que buscas es usar AJAX, sería:

```
$(document).on("change", "#buscarc" function(){

  var buscar = $(this).val();           

  $.ajax({
    url: "tuarchivo.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: { buscarc : buscar }
  }).done(function(data){
    alert(data);
  });

});
```

Espero te sirva, dime si tienes alguna duda.

Comment: Hola. Muchas gracias. Pero he intentado y no me funcionó. No sé porqué el change no me funciona. Estas es la librería que uso: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Es que ese código me (llamémoslo recepcion.php) recibe los daos de (por ejemplo) prueba.php. prueba.php me envía los datos a recepcion.php y este último los devuelve a prueba.php para hacer una consulta de datos en tiempo real.

Espero haberme hecho entender.

Comment: Entonces el segundo código, que usa la función Ajax, debería ser tu alternativa. Por otro lado no uses el font tag, usa un textarea, es probable que el change event no se desencadene en un tag que en rigor no tiene un valor, además el font tag está en desuso. Si necesitas contenido WYSIWYG te recomiendo TinyMCE o CKEditor: https://www.tiny.cloud/ https://ckeditor.com/ Quedo atento!

Comment: ¿Te soy sincero? Apenas soy un aprendiz (y tengo muchísimos deseos deseos de aprender lenguaje técnico), pero en realidad no te entendí. Parece que tienes buen manejo del tema.

Comment: En ese caso, te recomiendo seguir estos pasos: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/quick-start/ una vez que lo tengas funcionando, podrás detectar cambios sobre el textarea de TinyMCE.

Comment: Dale una vuelta y si gustas armas otra pregunta con ese código y la respondo. Si te sirvió esta información me ayudarías montón marcando la respuesta como correcta. ¡Éxito!